# Measuring time in C++ with high precision

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

How can i measure something in C++ as accurately as in C#?

This is my C# code

```
var elapsedMilliseconds = (double)(sw.ElapsedTicks * 1000L) / Stopwatch.Frequency;
```

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Just curious, why not use the build in `Stopwatch` property [`ElapsedMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx) in C#?

Comment: Is this link helpful: [How do I do High Resolution Timing in C++ on Windows?](http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsi2/a/timing.htm)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Stopwatch class in C# is based on these two Win32 API calls, which you can call from C/C++:

- [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Call the first function and divide it by the second function to get a value in seconds.

Example:

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq, start, end;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
// do some long operation here
Sleep(5000);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
// subtract before dividing to improve precision
double durationInSeconds = static_cast<double>(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / freq.QuadPart;
```

Note that the following comment in the documentation is real, and should be considered.  I'm personally observed this behavior in a VirtualBox virtual machine.  Differences of dozens of milliseconds can exist between different processors, leading to unexpected results such as negative durations and longer-than-expected durations:

> On a multiprocessor computer, it should not matter which processor is
>   called. However, you can get different results on different processors
>   due to bugs in the basic input/output system (BIOS) or the hardware
>   abstraction layer (HAL). To specify processor affinity for a thread,
>   use the SetThreadAffinityMask function.

You might be interested in this for more: [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch returns negative numbers in Elapsed... properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008345/system-diagnostics-stopwatch-returns-negative-numbers-in-elapsed-properties)

Note that the Stopwatch class falls back on GetTickCount if the above two APIs aren't available or return failure codes.  This is likely just to retain compatibility with Windows 9x; I've not encountered any issues myself with these APIs on modern PCs.  GetTickCount won't have the precision you want, however.

Comment: I believe that `QueryPerformanceCounter` is equivalent to `StopWatch.GetTimestamp`, and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` is equivalent to `StopWatch.Frequency`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a more specific measurement and found one. Thx for the other answers. They are all good. with this answer I can easily switch to Microseconds if needed.

Of course I will accept James Johnston answer as the right one because of the great explanation und the feedback of the people.

Thx all

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
unsigned long long nFreq = GetPerformanceTicksInSecond();
unsigned long long nBefore = GetPerformanceTicks();
timer start1 = timer::start();

CallSomeFunction();

unsigned long long nAfter = GetPerformanceTicks();
const unsigned long long nDiff = nAfter - nBefore;
const unsigned long long nMicroseconds = GetTickMicroseconds(nDiff,nFreq);

cout << "CallSomeFunction() took " << nMicroseconds << " " << time << endl;

return 0;

}

unsigned long long GetPerformanceTicks()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER nValue;

    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&nValue);

    return nValue.QuadPart;
}

unsigned long long GetPerformanceTicksInSecond()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER nFreq;

    ::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&nFreq);

    return nFreq.QuadPart;
}

double GetTickSeconds(unsigned long long nTicks,unsigned long long nFreq)
{
    return static_cast<double>(nTicks) / static_cast<double>(nFreq);
}

unsigned long long GetTickMilliseconds(unsigned long long nTicks,unsigned long long nFreq)
{
    unsigned long long nTicksInMillisecond = nFreq / 1000;

    return nTicks / nTicksInMillisecond;
}

unsigned long long GetTickMicroseconds(unsigned long long nTicks,unsigned long long nFreq)
{
    unsigned long long nTicksInMicrosecond = nFreq / 1000000;

    return nTicks / nTicksInMicrosecond;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this: [How to get system time in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599321/how-to-get-system-time-in-c)

also you can use GetTickCount which:
*Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started, up to 49.7 days.*

Comment: GetTickCount won't have the precision that the questioner wants; Stopwatch class is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter API functions.

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

LARGE_INTEGER start, end;
::QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
// do some work
::QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

double const t = double(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / double(freq.QuadPart);
```

To improve accuracy you may want to subtract the time it takes to call QueryPerformanceCounter from the result.

Answer (score 0):

The Stopwatch-class is a wrapper around QueryPerformanceCounter:

```
uint64_t startTime, endTime;
uint64_t frequency;
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&startTime);
//DoStuff
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&endTime);
double seconds = (endTime-startTime)/(double) frequency;
```