# c/c++ microsecond timestamp

Tags: c++, c, ctime, time.h

I used this piece of code to get timestamp in microsecond in c/c++. but it doesn't look like microsecond. also i don't know if there is any way to format it.

```
timeval curTime;
gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);
int milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000;
unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_usec*(uint64_t)1000000+curTime.tv_usec;

char buffer [80];
//localtime is not thread safe
strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&curTime.tv_sec));

char currentTime[84] = "";
char currentTime2[80] = "";
sprintf(currentTime, "%s:%3d", buffer, milli);
sprintf(currentTime2, "%s:%Lu", buffer, micro); 
printf("time %s, hptime %s\n", currentTime, currentTime2);
```

and what is the right format to output it? Thank you!

Comment: What is the significance of the line `unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_usec*(uint64_t)1000000+curTime.tv_usec;`?  Would it not be better as `unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_sec*(uint64_t)1000000+curTime.tv_usec;`?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the code, it seems only 
    unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_usec  
is needed.

Comment: Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) at least on  Linux

Comment: Related: [Getting an accurate execution time in C++ (micro seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856025/getting-an-accurate-execution-time-in-c-micro-seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical printing format for sub-second times uses the decimal indicator (`.` in many locales) and so 59 and some seconds might look like 59.00013.

The `micro` variable you created takes the current microsecond count, multiplies it by 1000000 then adds the current microsecond count again; I expect that you intend to either use the microsecond count alone, or together with the count of seconds:

```
unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_usec*(uint64_t)1000000+curTime.tv_usec;
```

should be written as

```
unsigned long micro = curTime.tv_sec*(uint64_t)1000000+curTime.tv_usec;
```

to get seconds and microseconds together in the same number.

To write this into your output, you might consider changing the line

```
sprintf(currentTime2, "%s:%Lu", buffer, micro);
```

to

```
sprintf(currentTime2, "%s.%Lu", buffer, curTime.tv_usec);
```

Using the altered `micro` definition, you can also output

```
sprintf(currentSeconds, "%.6f", micro / 1000000);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was too careless. was trying to get some quick and dirty result.

Answer (score 4):

Something a bit shorter to try (C++):

```
using namespace std::chrono;
__int64 microseconds_since_epoch = duration_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    cout << floor<microseconds>(system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

which just output for me:

```
2017-09-29 15:46:27.793195
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use visual studio (Windows environment),
How about to using WINDOWS API : [`GetLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlocaltime)

```
  char* lptszBuffer = new char[100]; 
  SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
  GetLocalTime( &sysTime );
  sprintf_s(lptszBuffer, 100, "[%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d]", sysTime.wHour, sysTime.wMinute, sysTime.wSecond, sysTime.wMilliseconds);
```

result format : `[11:27:00.027]`