# Does standard C++11 guarantee that high_resolution_clock measure real time (non CPU-cycles)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, performance-testing

As known `clock()` may show less than or greater than the value of the real time - both cases are shown in the following examples 1 and 2.

For high-precision measurements of the time in C++11 we can use:

- `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` - guarantee high-precision
- `std::chrono::steady_clock::now();` - guarantee that measure real time
- `clock();` - guarantee high-precision, but measure CPU-cycles instead of time
- `time(&t_start);` - isn't high-precision, but measure real time

**1-** For example: http://ideone.com/SudWTM

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main(void) {

    std::cout << "sleep(3) took: \n\n";

    clock_t c_start, c_end;
    time_t t_start, t_end;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point h_start, h_end;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point steady_start, steady_end;

    time(&t_start);  // less precise than clock() but always get the real actual time
    c_start = clock(); // clock() get only CPU-time, it can be more than real or less - sleep(3); took 0.00 seconds 
    h_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    steady_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); 

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    steady_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    h_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    c_end = clock();
    time(&t_end);

    std::cout << "highres = " << std::chrono::duration<double>(h_end - h_start).count() << " s \n";
    std::cout << "steady = " << std::chrono::duration<double>(steady_end - steady_start).count() << " s \n";

    printf("clock() = %.2lf seconds \n", (c_end - c_start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("time() = %.2lf seconds \n", difftime(t_end, t_start));

    return 0;
}
```

Result on g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2: **clock() = 0.00 seconds**

```
sleep(3) took: 

highres = 3.00098 s 
steady = 3.00098 s 
clock() = 0.00 seconds 
time() = 3.00 seconds
```

Result on C++ MSVS 2013 v120 (Windows 7x64):

```
sleep(3) took:

highres = 3.00017 s
steady = 3.00017 s
clock() = 3.00 seconds
time() = 3.00 seconds
```

**2-** Second example OpenMP or `<thread>`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2922c85385d197e1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {

    std::cout << "for-loop took: \n\n";

    clock_t c_start, c_end;
    time_t t_start, t_end;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point h_start, h_end;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point steady_start, steady_end;

    time(&t_start);  // less precise than clock() but always get the real actual time
    c_start = clock(); // clock() get only CPU-time, it can be more than real or less - sleep(3); took 0.00 seconds 
    h_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    steady_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
    {
        for (volatile int i = 0; i < 200000000; ++i);
    }

    steady_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    h_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    c_end = clock();
    time(&t_end);

    std::cout << "highres = " << std::chrono::duration<double>(h_end - h_start).count() << " s \n";
    std::cout << "steady = " << std::chrono::duration<double>(steady_end - steady_start).count() << " s \n";

    printf("clock() = %.2lf seconds \n", (c_end - c_start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("time() = %.2lf seconds \n", difftime(t_end, t_start));

    int b = getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Result on g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2: **clock() = 1.35 seconds**

```
for-loop took: 

highres = 0.213906 s 
steady = 0.213905 s 
clock() = 1.35 seconds 
time() = 0.00 seconds
```

Result on C++ MSVS 2013 v120 (Windows 7x64):

```
for-loop took:

highres = 1.49109 s
steady = 1.49109 s
clock() = 1.49 seconds
time() = 2.00 seconds
```

Resume:

1. When thread sleeps then `clock()` on g++ 4.9.2 doesn't measure time unlike other functions.
2. When we use multithreading by using OpenMP or by using `<thread>` ([link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2922c85385d197e1)), then `clock()` on g++ 4.9.2 measures CPU-cycles of all threads.

Also on Windows MSVS 2013 `clock()` measures required real time in both cases, but this doesn't guarantee that `clock()` measures the same on other platforms (on linux g++ is 0 for the sleep and x-fold for the multithreading).

Based on this, if `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` measures required real time in both cases on both Windows MSVS 2013 and g++ 4.9.2, does this guarantee that it will measure real high resolution time on all other platforms and does whether it guarantee standard C++11/14?

Comment: MSVC 2012 and MSVC 2013 has a known bug with ``std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`` where it's using system-time so it only has a 1 ms resolution. This is fixed in MSVC 2015.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Short answer: as of the C++14 standard, `high_resolution_clock` does NOT explicitly provide the guarantee you're looking for.

For now, `steady_clock` and `system_clock` provide better and more explicit guarantees. However, most implementations *probably will* ensure that HRC advances while its thread is sleeping. It may nevertheless be preferable to do your own type-aliasing. See 'EDIT' sections below and discussion in comments.

#### Long answer:

The [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) does in fact implicitly acknowledge (in note 30.2.4 "Timing Specifications", note 5) that Clock objects are **not** required to advance while their associated thread is sleeping. For context, this section is explaining how the standard-library timer objects work; the behavior of a timer is based on the behavior of the clock used to set it.

> [ *Note:* If the clock is not synchronized with a steady clock, e.g., a
>   CPU time clock, these timeouts might not provide useful functionality.
>   — *end note* ]

Note that in this case, "timeouts might not provide useful functionality" means that if you use a timer to `sleep_until` a particular clock time *using an unsynchronized (non-realtime) clock*, your thread *will not wake up*. So the note above is a bit of an understatement.

And, indeed, there is nothing in the Clock specification (20.13.3) that actually requires synchronization with a steady clock.

However, the standard appears to implicitly condone two potential aliases for `high_resolution_clock` in the definition in 20.13.7.3:

> `high_resolution_clock` may be a synonym for `system_clock` or
>   `steady_clock`.

`steady_clock` is, of course, steady. `system_clock` is **not**, because the system time could change (e.g. as the result of an NTP update) while the program is running.

However, `system_clock` (20.13.7.1) **is** still a "realtime" clock:

> Objects of class `system_clock` represent wall clock time from the
>   system-wide realtime clock.

So `system_clock` **will not** stop advancing when your thread sleeps. 
This confirms Nicol Bolas's point that a `is_steady` may be *false* for `high_resolution_clock` even if the clock behaves as you expect (i.e. it advances regardless of the state of its associated thread).

Based on this, it seems reasonable to expect most mainstream implementations to use a realtime (i.e. synchronized) clock of some sort for `high_resolution_clock`. Implementations are designed to be useful, after all, and a clock is generally less useful if it's not realtime, especially if it's used with timers as per the note on "useful functionality" above.

Since it's not *guaranteed*, however, you should check the behavior and/or documentation of each implementation you want to use.

**EDIT:** I've started a [discussion on the ISO C++ Standards group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/D_S47zTnNmw) on the issue, suggesting that this is a bug in the standard. The first reply, from Howard Hinnant, who takes credit for putting it *in* the standard, is worth quoting:

> I would not be opposed to deprecating `high_resolution_clock`, with the intent to remove it after a suitable period of deprecation.  The reality is that it is always a typedef to either `steady_clock` or `system_clock`, and the programmer is better off choosing one of those two and know what he’s getting, than choose `high_resolution_clock` and get some other clock by a roll of the dice.

...So the moral, according to Hinnant, is **don't use `high_resolution_clock`.**

**EDIT 2:**

The problem with `high_resolution_clock` according to Hinnant is not so much that you're likely to run into a problem with HRC (although that *is* possible even with a conforming compiler, as per the argument above), but that since you're typically not actually getting a lower resolution than you could with the one of the other two clocks (though you'll need to manually compare their resolutions in a type-alias or typedef to get a "maximum resolution" non-sleeping clock), there's no concrete benefit. So you need to weigh the risk of having threads sleep forever on conforming implementations versus the semantic benefit of the name `high_resolution_clock` and the simplicity/brevity benefit of avoiding just making your own typedef or type-alias.

Here's some actual code for various approaches:

- Use `static_assert` to *check* whether `high_resolution_clock` is actually aliased to a real clock. This will *probably* never fire, which means that you're automatically getting the highest-resolution "realtime" clock without messing with your own typedefs:

  ```
   static_assert(
        std::is_same<high_resolution_clock, steady_clock>::value
     || std::is_same<high_resolution_clock, system_clock>::value,
     "high_resolution_clock IS NOT aliased to one of the other standard clocks!");
  ```
- Use the HRC if `high_resolution_clock::is_steady` is true; otherwise prefer the higher-resolution clock between `system_clock` and `steady_clock`. **NOTE** that if `high_resolution_clock::is_steady` is false, this *probably* just means that the HRC is aliased to `system_clock`, in which case you'll ultimately end up with a new type-alias that is actually the same type as `high_resolution_clock`. However, creating your own type-alias makes this explicit and guarantees that even a malicious-but-conforming implementation won't have the issue outlined above.

  ```
  using maxres_sys_or_steady =
      std::conditional<
          system_clock::period::den <= steady_clock::period::den,
          system_clock, steady_clock
        >::type;
  using maxres_nonsleeping_clock =
      std::conditional<
          high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
          high_resolution_clock, maxres_sys_or_steady
        >::type;
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I.e. the clock to be useful for a multi-threaded program, they must necessarily be steady, and maximize resolution as possible. Then I should use something like this: `typedef std::conditional<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock >::type maxres_steady_clock;` http://ideone.com/uqSyZY  Also if I want to count time spent by all threads in this process http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2922c85385d197e1  then I can use `clock()` on gcc (linux_x86), but not on MSVS (Windows). Isn't it?

Comment: An additional would be good to have a standard measurement function of spent CPU cycles - i.e. resource consumption of the specific code - it repeatable value (except of using hyper threading, if the second thread on the same core occupied same ALU or ports https://habrastorage.org/files/b7c/1f3/f80/b7c1f3f80caf4f3a9a2b0ecf5c3bbc9d.jpg ), but this measurement excludes (1) effect of the other threads, which occupy a core and displace our thread, also excludes (2) throttling effect or accelerated when speeded up by the (3) turbo boost.

Comment: I don't care if Howard Hinnant designed the library; his "moral" is wrong. If he believes that HRC was a bad idea, then he's wrong. The usefulness of HRC as a distinct type is clear.

Comment: @NicolBolas Indeed: I agree entirely with your post in response to Hinnant. But if "in practice" `high_resolution_clock` is **currently** aliased to either `steady_clock` or `system_clock` in almost all implementations, then Hinnant is correct that **for now** it's better to simply pick one explicitly. So if the specification for `high_resolution_clock` changes in the 17 standard, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand: But how do you define "almost all implementations?" By majority? So if VS's has a distinct HRC while libc++ and libstdc++ don't, then it's OK to just ignore the fact that you're going to get crappy resolution in VS's non-HRC clocks? That's not a good plan for portable code.

Comment: @Alex As noted in the answer, "steadiness" is not actually what you're looking for (unless you're *also* concerned about the system clock going backwards while your app is running, as in my NTP example). You want the highest resolution clock available that *is guaranteed not to pause while your thread is paused*. If Hinnant's statement is anything to go by, `high_resolution_clock` *does* typically provide this, but this is *not* guaranteed *by the standard*. So instead of checking `is_steady`, you should compare the period-denominator of `system_clock` to that of `steady_clock`.

Comment: `using maxres_steady_clock =
    std::conditional<
        std::chrono::system_clock::period::den <= std::chrono::steady_clock::period::den,
        std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock
      >::type;`

Comment: @NicolBolas What makes you certain that HRC clocks in VS have higher resolution than *both* `system_clock` *and* `steady_clock`? I don't have a real version of MSVS in front of me, but [if this version is close enough, that doesn't appear to be true](http://rextester.com/DZRM21015).

Comment: @KyleStrand: "*So instead of checking is_steady, you should compare the period-denominator of system_clock to that of steady_clock.*" That makes no sense. The system clock can *change*; it's *never* appropriate for this use case, no matter what the "period-denominator" is.

Comment: @KyleStrand: "*What makes you certain that HRC clocks in VS have higher resolution than both system_clock and steady_clock?*" My point wasn't about a specific case. My point is how to define "almost all implementations" Do we have actual information about how most standard libraries implement HRC, or is that just guesswork from looking at Clang and GCC?

Comment: Also note that you can simply *check* whether `high_resolution_clock` is aliased to `system_clock` or `steady_clock` as per Hinnant's claim: `  static_assert(
         std::is_same<high_resolution_clock, steady_clock>::value
      || std::is_same<high_resolution_clock, system_clock>::value,
      "high_resolution_clock IS NOT aliased to one of the other standard clocks!");` If this ever **actually fires**, that would be the time to look for alternate strategies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116825/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-nicol-bolas).

Comment: @KyleStrand, @NicolBolas:  Here is a `<chrono>` clock implementation survey:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/clock_survey.html

Comment: Good answer and discussion. Upvoted. However, the comparison between the two `den`s seems wrong: a bigger `den` means higher resolution, and should be preferred. I'd also prefer to use the `steady_clock` if it has the same resolution as `system_clock`, so I would change `<=` to `>` in `system_clock::period::den <= steady_clock::period::den`.

Answer (score 9):

The standard does not specify this behavior from its clocks. Not exactly.

A clock has the `is_steady` static property, which can be checked. Any clock for which `is_steady` returns true *cannot* be the sort of clock that stops running just because you put a thread to sleep. However, a clock for which that value is false could be non-steady for a variety of reasons. It may not be steady because it's a wall clock that will change if the system time changes. Or because the period between ticks is an average, rather than an exact number.

So `is_steady` does not really answer your question.

The standard does not specify `high_resolution_clock::is_steady`, but it does require the implementation to answer that question. If it is steady, then you are guaranteed that sleeping a thread won't stop the clock. But if it's not steady... you get no guarantee at all.

Comment: Thank you! I.e. if I need a cross-platform measurement of time necessarily steady, and preferably accurate, I need to use something like this: `typedef std::conditional<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, std::chrono::steady_clock >::type maxres_steady_clock;`

Comment: @Alex: If you need cross-platform measurement of time that is steady, you should use `steady_clock`. If you need cross-platform time measurement that gives you the highest resolution possible, then you should use `high_resolution_clock`. If the latter isn't steady, that's probably because the platform cannot make it steady without losing resolution. So... which is more important to you? And please remember: lack of `is_steady` ***does not mean*** that it will stop just because you paused the thread. `is_steady` is not the answer to the question you are asking.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that. But what else now can guarantees that it will not stop just because you paused the thread, besides `is_steady`? And I don't understand for what can I use HRC if it measures something with highres, but it is unknown what (not the physical time), or is this value guaranteed that repeatable independently of CPU-clock up/down, CPU stalls, number threads in process (as in `clock()`), ... and can I use it as guaranteed repeatable performance counter for short single-thread part of code?

Comment: @Alex: You could just use the HRC and not worry about it. Implementations are not stupid, nor are they deliberately trying to break your code. Just because the standard doesn't guarantee something doesn't mean that you can't reasonably rely on it. You rely on copy elision, right? That's a quality-of-implementation feature. What's wrong with relying on reasonable behavior from the HRC as a QOI feature?

Comment: I hope the implementation of HRC will never be as good as `clock()` implementation.