# Reliably compare different machine's timestamps in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, timestamp

I have three machines `A, B, C` connected via Ethernet. `A` will send UDP packets to `B` which will forward it to `C`. I want to reliably measure the propagation time. Assume that the three machines are time-sync'd using a local `NTP server`.

What's the best way of generating a timestamp in `C++`? My current guess would be `chrono`. The way I understand it is that its `high_resolution_clock` is out of the question here because it can use things like a CPU register that is incremented on each operation. So this would vary wildly depending on when the machine was booted. Instead I will go with `steady_clock` that will use the synchronized system time but hopefully prevent me from getting into trouble with things like leap seconds which matter if I used `system_clock`.

Am I right in these assumptions? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Which operating system/toolchain are you targeting?

Comment: Linux (some Ubuntu variant), things are sent out using boost::asio. Whenever something is sent, the source will remember the timestamp it sent that packet. The sink will remember the timestamps of arrivals. Both are pinged periodically for this data.

Comment: Ignore leap seconds. If you detect that a leap second happened during or around a measurement, discard that measurement. Much easier than special cases to handle with an event that happens at most every six months.

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steady clock won't help you at all, since it's not the wall clock and it can by definition not be synchronized (it's steady, NTP can't change it). So your only option is the wall clock / system clock.

However one of your problems will be that the time synchronization through NTP is not very exact. If you want to compare timestamps in the dimensions of seconds it might be ok. For everything else your clocks will often be too far off to deliver good results.

There are dedicated protocols for synchronizing clocks between different machines, e.g. PTP and gPTP. Some of those will even require dedicated hardware (like Ethernet AVB capable hardware). If you need to precision then your first research should be how to integrate on of those into your system and how to read their timestamps.

Comment: Good point about PTP. NTP's guarantees on time precision are pretty broad and not very useful if you want to time packets on a local network.

Comment: This link (https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/discipline.html) states that on a fast LAN, NTP can "maintain synchronization nominally within one millisecond". That would be fine for me and is far more precise than seconds...

Comment: Your question is mentioning measuring packet latency. On LAN the latency of UDP packets will be in the microsecond range. So I guessed you need a high precision, and these protocols were developed to achieve that.

Comment: And often not only the average time difference will be interesting but how much the clocks drift relative to each other. Some approaches will yield a much higher clock jitter than others, which would have a high impact on certain types of realtime applications. But of course I don't know whether that matters for your specific problem.

Comment: @kunterbunt This question is pretty much answered, use `system_clock`, but the answer won't do you much good. You have two other problems: 1 High precision time capable of detecting propagation delay where the the propagation delay is likely to be microseconds. This is a difficult problem on PC hardware because as you get below ms resolution time gets increasingly dodgy. 2. Synchronizing multiple PCs and keeping them locked with precision to support problem 1.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will be simulating other channel types on the machine that forwards the packets. The times I will be measuring will be in a range of milliseconds, and being off by some micro- or milliseconds is not critical for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. `high_resolution_clock` is almost always (if not always) either `steady_clock` or `system_clock`, so it could be a universal wall time or a machine-specific counter. You don't really know which you will get. A discussion worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253266/4581301
2. [`steady_clock` is not the clock for you.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) There is no guaranteed correlation between `steady_clock`s on different machines.

This leaves you with `system_clock` or an implementation-specific clock.