# what is the best practice for storing date and time in class/object?

Tags: c++, postgresql, date, datetime, time

recently i'm going to connect to PostgreSQL and I need to store date/time in my object to pass to the query for insert and update some table.
but there is not clear way in c++ to store and retrieve date/time.
any comment?

Comment: You can covert it to milliseconds from epoch. You might want to look at `chrono` namespace

Comment: With what precision was the data stored in the database? if it's +-1 second, well, then a `time_t`willl do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PostgreSQL TimeFormat 9+ version* https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html

Which is a `8byte int(64 bit)` time format in `microsecond` precision, UTC without timezone (from top of the table).

When you create a table you can either time-stamp the record by PostgreSQL `current_timestamp` , OR insert into table as integer `64bit microsecond format`. since PostgreSQL has multiple time format you should decide time any the format you want from table

> PostgreSQL approach CREATE,INSERT,RETRIEVE

```
"CREATE TABLE example_table(update_time_column TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"

"INSERT INTO example_table(update_time_column) VALUES update_time_column=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

"SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch FROM update_time_column)*1000000) FROM example_table"
```

> C++ approach

```
auto/int64_t cppTime = get64bitMicrosecondFormat from some library`
```

something similar to this answer: [Getting an accurate execution time in C++ (micro seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856025/getting-an-accurate-execution-time-in-c-micro-seconds)

Then push your object / record to PostGRESQL, when retrieve in microseconds, adjust precision `/1000 for milliseconds` etc.

> Just don't forget to synchronize PostgreSQL and C++ timestamp length (eg. 8byte - 8byte each side) otherwise, your time will be thresholded either side, and you will lose precision / get unexpected time.