# Timer in C++ with milliseconds. Problems with pause time

Tags: c++

As I mentioned in the post title, I'm just starting out in the world of C++. I want to create a timer that is as accurate as possible (real-time, not a simple countdown), including milliseconds. And it's from this point on, that is, adding milliseconds, that the problems begin. If I only leave it up to the seconds, giving it a pause of 1000 milliseconds, everything seems to work fine, but when I add it to make it more complete with milliseconds (giving it a pause in microseconds, 1000 = 1 millisecond, since I convert all the time to milliseconds), the time passes too quickly or too slowly. Here is the code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

void countdown(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds) {
  int total_milliseconds = (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000 + milliseconds;
  int current_milliseconds = total_milliseconds;
  //auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  while (current_milliseconds > 0) {
  auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    current_milliseconds -= 1;
    int remaining_milliseconds = current_milliseconds % 1000;
    int remaining_seconds = current_milliseconds / 1000 % 60;
    int remaining_minutes = current_milliseconds / 1000 / 60 % 60;
    int remaining_hours = current_milliseconds / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", remaining_hours, remaining_minutes, remaining_seconds, remaining_milliseconds);
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
    
    int wait_time = current_milliseconds - elapsed_time;
    //std::cout << wait_time << " ";
    if (wait_time > 0) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
    }
  }
  Beep(440, 1000);
}

int main() {
  countdown(0, 0, 2, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried to incorporate the fact of taking the time and subtracting it, so that regardless of the processor tasks or the time it takes, it can always be subtracted exactly the same. Another thing, I also do not manage to show only one line and in each frame it erases the screen for me. I know that in some logic I must be failing. I hope you can guide me, greetings Leopoldo.

The result right now is slower than in reality.

Comment: Your description is not clear what you try to solve. [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for): *This function may block for longer than `sleep_duration` due to scheduling or resource contention delays.* - this might be your issue.

Comment: Please be aware that the operation system has only a limited timing accuracy. Depending on the Windows version you can configure it in a certain range. Typical defaults are 15ms or 50ms.

Comment: I'd recommend sticking to the `std::chrono` units wherever you can. You're already using chrono, but you're doing conversions manually when the library already provides clear, safe ways of doing them.

Comment: Besides mentioned `sleep_for()` inaccuracy, as well as any delay function in non-realtime OS, the rest of your code also takes time to execute, especially terminal output. You can use `std::this_thread::sleep_until()` to improve accuracy. Keep in mind different clock types.

Comment: This question has two great answers so far. Please review and make sure to upvote and mark the post that best answers your question as the correct answer. For future reference, please precise with whatever your issue is. I myself had to decipher what your issue was by reading your post multiple times.

Comment: See also: [Getting an accurate execution time in C++ (micro seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21856025/4561887)

Comment: Leo, be sure to vote up any helpful answer, and mark one correct if one fully solves your problem. One upvote is better than 100 "thank yous".

Answer (score 0):

The cardinal rule is that when your program asks the OS to make it sleep for a given time, the *actual* time spent sleeping is simply not going to be time requested. The time you specify to `sleep_for` is only a vague suggestion to the OS. This is without even accounting for any slowness of your program itself. With that in mind, your algorithm seems all jumbled up. Here's what you should be doing, in English:

1. Note the time the countdown should end.
2. Note the current time.

   - Print whatever messages here.
3. If the current time is more than 1 ms away from the end time:

   1. Sleep for *about* 1 ms (you can only *approximately* set the sleep time!)
   2. Go to 2.

Notice that some times around the loop you might end up in the same millisecond, and some times you'll skip some messages. You could add logic to avoid duplicate messages (I won't). You can't really avoid a missing message except by means outside your process (increase priority to the OS, use a real-time OS, buy a faster processor, etc.), since that means your program simply didn't have enough time. In very particular, the line in your code `current_milliseconds -= 1` has completely the wrong idea. There is absolutely no reason for one millisecond to have passed between iterations of your loop.

Now the above procedure in C++:

```
void countdown(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds) {
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

  auto start_time = clock::now();
  clock::duration remaining_wait =
      std::chrono::hours(hours) +
      std::chrono::minutes(minutes) +
      std::chrono::seconds(seconds) +
      std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds);
  auto end_time = start_time + remaining_wait; // Step 1

  while(remaining_wait > 0ms) {
    // there's probably a better way to do this...
    auto display_wait = remaining_wait;
    auto remaining_hours =
        std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::hours>(display_wait);
    auto remaining_minutes =
        std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::minutes>(display_wait -= remaining_hours);
    auto remaining_seconds =
        std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(display_wait -= remaining_minutes);
    auto remaining_milliseconds =
        std::chrono::round<std::chrono::milliseconds>(display_wait -= remaining_seconds);
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n", int(remaining_hours.count()), int(remaining_minutes.count()), int(remaining_seconds.count()), int(remaining_milliseconds.count()));

    remaining_wait = end_time - clock::now(); // Step 2

    auto sleep_quantum = 1ms;
    if(remaining_wait > sleep_quantum) std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleep_quantum); // Step 3
  }
  Beep(440, 1000);
}
```

This achieves better than 1% accuracy on my machine for a 2 second wait (as measured by the *nix `time` command, a few runs of the program have execution times in the range 2007-2010 ms). As expected, I get some duplicate and (many) missing messages, even though the overall duration is correct.

Comment: Hello HTNW. Thank you for taking the time to help me. I'm going to study your code and incorporate your advice. Greetings Leopoldo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a countdown function that resolves all of your issues. Copy and paste and say goodbye to your problems:

```
// Dependencies | std
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

void efficientFixedCountdown(const std::chrono::nanoseconds& countdownDuration, const std::chrono::nanoseconds& tickInterval) {
    // Local variables used to control fixed updating of countdown timer
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> bootTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::nanoseconds fixedTime = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
    std::chrono::nanoseconds deltaTime = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);

    // While there is more time left to coundown, countdown
    while (countdownDuration > fixedTime) {
        // If it is time to countdown according to tickrate, countdown
        if (fixedTime + deltaTime < std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - bootTime) {
            // Convert nanoseconds to hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds
            std::chrono::nanoseconds timeLeft = countdownDuration - fixedTime;
            std::chrono::hours hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(timeLeft);
            std::chrono::minutes minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(timeLeft % std::chrono::hours(1));
            std::chrono::seconds seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(timeLeft % std::chrono::minutes(1));
            std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeLeft % std::chrono::seconds(1));

            // Print leftover time
            std::cout << hours.count() << " hours, " << minutes.count() << " minutes, " << seconds.count() << " seconds, " << milliseconds.count() << " milliseconds\n";

            // Conserve resources and iterations
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() + tickInterval);

            // Update fixed time
            fixedTime += tickInterval;
        }
    }
    
    Beep(440, 1000);
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Program operating" << std::endl;

    efficientFixedCountdown(std::chrono::seconds(10), std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

    std::cout << "Program terminated" << std::endl;
}
```

This way of updating your timer is similar to what game engines use. There is a real time update and a fixed time update. If you want it to seem like it is ticking at 100% precision, you need to treat the time as your system updating at that specific time point by capturing when the time you want it to update has passed, update your system / clock/ code at the update rate or tick rate you set it and update your fixed time that used by your system / clock / code.

Also, `std::chrono::nanoseconds` is the most precise you can get with time. By setting the parameters to `std::chrono::nanoseconds` any time data type you passed will be up casted to that, so you can cover any type of duration and tick rate with ease.

Comment: Be really careful with `high_resolution_clock`. It's speced loosely and, depending on what clock it potentially aliases, isn't necessarily monotonic. It can jump around in time and even go backward. Normally this is a timing problem, but when you're clocking in the millisecond range the jitter can be murderous. Prefer a `steady_clock`.

Comment: Hello Christopher,
Thank you for taking the time to help me. It is very interesting the approach you take to the problem. I will also study your contributions carefully in order to understand them. Best regards, Leopoldo.

Comment: @user4581301 Can you elaborate more on your point? I am really interested in hearing what you have to say.

Comment: Here's a question answered by one of the guys who designed the chrono library: [What are the uses of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37426832/4581301). TL;DR version: "There are none."

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things here:

1. You assume that your thread is sleeping exectally 1ms, which is not the case. If you are running your code on a „normal“ os there ist no guarantee that the scheduler will schedule your task with nearly the precission you assume.
2. You call printf, which will delay your program by quite a bit.
3. You do not consider the time consumed to execute instructions before and after calling the clock and the calls to the clock itselve.

I think what you trying to achieve is not really possible. Things just do not work this way.
Implement thinks with the fact in mind that timings will most likely never be accurate and account for that with a more event driven approach of programming.

But as a general hint: Consider to use chrono::steady_clock to calculate time differences.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).