# can we use two break statements in a single while(1) loop?

Tags: c

Following is my program. I am trying to read characters at different baud rate and if no character is received within 10 seconds I want to break out of the loop and similarily if any character other than alphabets is received, I again want to break out of the loop? How can I do that. Please guide me.

```
char read()
{
    while(1)
    {
        delay_ms(10000);
        break;

        if((uart_RxChar() >= 65 && uart_RxChar() <= 90) || (uart_RxChar() >= 97 && uart_RxChar() >= 122))
        {
            uart_TxChar('k');
            Glow_GreenLED();
        }
        else 
        {
            Glow_RedLED();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `delay_ms()` will,help you wait for 10 seconds....it's an unconditional think..it will make you wait.

Comment: Break after delay_ms() is doble.

Comment: `uart_RxChar()` is not a standard C library function.  Post some link that documents its functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char read()
{
   while(1)
   {
       delay_ms(10000); // Stops the program
       break; // Then leaves

       if( (uart_RxChar() >= 65 && uart_RxChar() <= 90) || (uart_RxChar() >= 97 && uart_RxChar() >= 122))
       {

           uart_TxChar('k');
           Glow_GreenLED();
       }
       else 
       {
           Glow_RedLED();
           break;
       }
    }
 }
```

What you are trying to do *won't succeed*. You have to know that delays don't work that way. When your program will reach to the delay, it **will stop everything** - inputs too - during the delay. Meaning that whatever you do, it will wait then break.
The only way to achieve what you want to do using delays is to use threads, and have one thread waiting and mesuring the time, and an other thread waiting for an input. A way to do this without threads is using a `timer` and use the value of the timer as a condition to break. May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167949/how-to-use-timer-in-c) could help. 
Nevertheless, it is perfectly possible to have *as much break* conditions as you want :

```
if (CONDITION_1) 
    break;
else if (CONDITION_2) 
{ 
      printf("something");
      break;
}
else if (CONDITION_3) 
{
      someFunction();
      break;
}
else 
      break;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first `break;` you get to, will break out of the loop, meaning,

```
   while(1)
   {
    delay_ms(10000);
     break;
```

is the same as

```
delay_ms(10000);
```

Your second `break;` as well as your whole `if-else` is "cut out" since the loop will break before

Comment: if I use the delay_ms(1000) outside while(1) loop, will it work?

Comment: What will work? the _delay_ms(1000)_ will be executed either way. If you want to delay AND check if any character other than alphabets is received, I suggest you'll look into threads

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question, I just want to give the function a specific time frame to execute and if didn't execute in that slot, it should return control to the next statement in main() >

Comment: using _delay_ms(X)_ will not give your _read()_ X ms to work, if that's what you meant. It will delay X ms and then continue from there - in your case, it will break. If you want _read()_ to execute in that time frame, you should consider threads, where one starts _read()_ and one is timing it