# C Array of request

Tags: c, request

If I have the structure and I want to have an `array of requests to type`
so then for example, I can use like `type->x` and `type->y`. How can I implement it?

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
} Test;
```

I appreciate any explanation.

EDIT: I change the name of variables to make it a clear that I will not use time library.

Comment: Your description seems a bit vague to me.  What's a "request to time"?

Comment: I think that he wants to create an array of time range structs associated with requests. (HTTP requests?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  `time.h` library

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm

for code for a timer see [How to use timer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167949/how-to-use-timer-in-c)

the elements of your `struct` are then of type `time_t` or `clock_t`
update :

you mean what a `struct` is...

basically a structure is acollection of data that is internally / logically related and the `struct` ensures that it is stored as a block in memory

the elements of a structure can either be variables or pointers to variables

the structure as a whole can also be accessed either as pointer or as variable

to access elements of a struct as variable use the `.`

to access elements of a struct as pointer use the `->`

foo->bar is equivalent to (*foo).bar, i.e. it gets the member called bar from the struct that foo points to.

[Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Comment: I give the name 'time' as example. I will work with other thing, like x and y

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help. Know I got it