# How can i run a function after n seconds in C?

Tags: c

My project is create a programs like Memcached. The program is store list of key , values and and the expiry time of the cached item.Its mean after n seconds a data will be remove. I think I can use `struct` to store key and values, but i can not remove a data after n seconds, Can you give me some solution? Thanks for all

Comment: Lookup timers in C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167949/how-to-use-timer-in-c
There are some platform specific APIs too, but since you don't specify that platform I can't link you that.

Comment: I know how to use basic timer, but i think my problem bigger, I need to store a lot off data to struct, each data have different expiry time, When expiry time = 0, i need remove this data

Comment: Your problem can be solved with this timer. That said, if it's not suitable for some reason, as I said there are platform specific APIs you can use. On Linux, for example, there is https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: I just use Dev-C to write this code, It is lab C

Comment: Can you give me some functions can solve this problem, I mean how run a funtion delete data after n seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the delete lazily.

You don't need to delete expired data immediately. In order to maintain the semantics of the data store, you only need to do two things:

1. Not return expired data to a query. (But see below.)
2. Not allow the datastore to fill up with expired data.

In other words, it is sufficient to delete expired data when you happen to encounter it, either because it showed up as the response to a query or because it occupies a slot which you need to store an update.

To simplify detection of expired data, you should store the actual expiry time in the structure, not the time to live. Then it's easy to see whether a key/value pair has expired: you just compare the expiry time to the current time.

If you use a chained hash, you can edit the hash chain (by removing expired entries) during a search of that chain. If you use open addressing, you can replaced expired entries with a tombstone (or you can use expiry as a tombstone). In both cases, if you find the key you are looking for but the entry is expired, you can terminate the search, either returning "key not present" if it's a query or by overwriting the data (and expiry time) with the new data if it's an update.

---

#### Note:

1. The data store cannot really guarantee that expired data will never be returned, since it does not control the network latency for responses. It is quite possible that the data it returns had not expired at the moment that it was despatched from the server, but has expired by the time it arrives at the client. So the data store can only offer "best effort", and it is up to the client to decide whether or not to use the data returned (and it is important that the server return the expiry time along with the data as a response to a query).

   Since the client must check the expiry time anyway, it would not be a definitive technical violation of the contract if the data store only checked expiry dates when it was updating an entry. But since the cost of not sending definitely expired data is so small that it's hardly worth worrying about, it seems reasonable to include the check in queries as well as updates.

Answer (score 0):

What about using timer?

> You can use a time_t struct and `clock()` function from *time.h*.
>
> Store the start time in a time_t struct by using `clock()` and check the
> elapsed time by comparing the difference between stored time and
> current time.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167949/how-to-use-timer-in-c) is explained.

Comment: This is a bad solution because it causes the process to consume processor time needlessly.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that there is more than one data stored at a time, and the expiration time is also different, I want to delete that data as soon as it expires, but how can the program always count? The time for each data is stored in the struct