# Column wise sum V row wise sum: Why don't I see a difference using NumPy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I've tested an example demonstrated in this [talk](http://www.pytables.org/docs/LargeDataAnalysis.pdf) [pytables] using numpy (page 20/57).

It is stated, that `a[:,1].sum()` takes 9.3 ms, whereas `a[1,:].sum()` takes only 72 us.

I tried to reproduce it, but failed to do so. Am I measuring wrongly? Or have things changed in NumPy since 2010?

```
$ python2 -m timeit -n1000 --setup \ 
  'import numpy as np; a = np.random.randn(4000,4000);' 'a[:,1].sum()' 
1000 loops, best of 3: 16.5 usec per loop

$ python2 -m timeit -n1000 --setup \ 
  'import numpy as np; a = np.random.randn(4000,4000);' 'a[1,:].sum()' 
1000 loops, best of 3: 13.8 usec per loop

$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.7
$ python2 -c 'import numpy; print numpy.version.version'
1.8.1
```

While I can measure a benefit of the second version (supposedly fewer cache misses because numpy uses C-style row ordering), I don't see that drastic difference as stated by the pytables contributor.

Also, it seems I cannot see more cache misses when using column V row summation.

---

**EDIT**

- So far the insight for me was that I was using the `timeit` module in the wrong way. Repeated runs with the same array (or row/column of an array) will almost certainly be cached (I've got `32KiB` of L1 data cache, so a line fits well inside: `4000 * 4 byte = 15k < 32k`).
- Using the script in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24738454/543411) of @alim with a single loop (`nloop=1`) and ten trials `nrep=10`, and varying the size of the random array (`n x n`) I am measuring

  ```
   n   row/us col/us    penalty col
   1k     90    100         1
   4k    100    210         2
  10k*   110    350         3.5
  20k*   120   1200        10
  ```

  * `n=10k` and higher doesn't fit into the L1d cache anymore.

I'm still not sure about tracing down the cause of this as `perf` shows about the same rate of cache misses (sometimes even a higher rate) for the faster row sum.

### `Perf` data:

`nloop = 2` and `nrep=2`, so I expect some of the data still in the cache... for the second run.

#### Row sum `n=10k`

```
 perf stat -B -e cache-references,cache-misses,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,L1-dcache-store-misses,L1-dcache-prefetches,cycles,instructions,branches,faults,migrations ./answer1.py 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /g'
row sum:    103.593 us
 Performance counter stats for './answer1.py':
          25850670      cache-references                                             [30.04%]
           1321945      cache-misses              #    5.114 % of all cache refs     [20.04%]
        5706371393      L1-dcache-loads                                              [20.00%]
          11733777      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.21% of all L1-dcache hits   [19.97%]
        2401264190      L1-dcache-stores                                             [20.04%]
         131964213      L1-dcache-store-misses                                       [20.03%]
           2007640      L1-dcache-prefetches                                         [20.04%]
       21894150686      cycles                    [20.02%]
       24582770606      instructions              #    1.12  insns per cycle         [30.06%]
        3534308182      branches                                                     [30.01%]
              3767      faults
                 6      migrations
       7.331092823 seconds time elapsed
```

#### Column sum `n=10k`

```
 perf stat -B -e cache-references,cache-misses,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,L1-dcache-store-misses,L1-dcache-prefetches,cycles,instructions,branches,faults,migrations ./answer1.py 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /g'
column sum: 377.059 us
 Performance counter stats for './answer1.py':
          26673628      cache-references                                             [30.02%]
           1409989      cache-misses              #    5.286 % of all cache refs     [20.07%]
        5676222625      L1-dcache-loads                                              [20.06%]
          11050999      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.19% of all L1-dcache hits   [19.99%]
        2405281776      L1-dcache-stores                                             [20.01%]
         126425747      L1-dcache-store-misses                                       [20.02%]
           2128076      L1-dcache-prefetches                                         [20.04%]
       21876671763      cycles                    [20.00%]
       24607897857      instructions              #    1.12  insns per cycle         [30.00%]
        3536753654      branches                                                     [29.98%]
              3763      faults
                 9      migrations
       7.327833360 seconds time elapsed
```

---

**EDIT2**
I think I have understood some aspects, but the question has not been answered yet I think.  At the moment I think this summation example doesn't reveal anything about CPU caches at all. In order to eliminate uncertainty by numpy/python, I tried to use `perf` on doing the summation in *C*, and the results are in an answer below.

Comment: I see the full order of magnitude difference both with a 64 bit Windows numpy 1.8.1 , and with a 32 bit Windows numpy master. What hardware are you using?

Comment: What are the sizes of the CPU caches on your computer?

Comment: From `lscpu` I'm reading `Architecture: x86_64, CPU(s): 2, Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6850  @ 3.00GHz, L1d cache: 32K, L1i cache:  32K, L2 cache:  4096K`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with your attempt at replication, but bear in mind that those slides are from 2010, and numpy has changed rather a lot since then. Based on the [dates of numpy releases](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases), I would guess that Francesc was probably using v1.5.

Using this script to benchmark row v column sums:

```
#!python

import numpy as np
import timeit

print "numpy version == " + str(np.__version__)

setup = "import numpy as np; a = np.random.randn(4000, 4000)"

rsum = "a[1, :].sum()"
csum = "a[:, 1].sum()"

nloop = 1000
nrep = 3

print "row sum:\t%.3f us" % (
    min(timeit.repeat(rsum, setup, repeat=nrep, number=nloop)) / nloop * 1E6)
print "column sum:\t%.3f us" % (
    min(timeit.repeat(csum, setup, repeat=nrep, number=nloop)) / nloop * 1E6)
```

I detect about a 50% slowdown for column sums with numpy v1.5:

```
$ python sum_benchmark.py 
numpy version == 1.5.0
row sum:        8.472 us
column sum:     12.759 us
```

Compared with about a 30% slowdown with v1.8.1, which you're using:

```
$ python sum_benchmark.py 
numpy version == 1.8.1
row sum:        12.108 us
column sum:     15.768 us
```

It's interesting to note that both types of reduction have actually gotten a bit slower in the more recent numpy versions. I would have to delve a lot deeper into numpy's source code 
to understand exactly why this is the case.

### Update

- For the record, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel v3.13.0-30) on a quad-core i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.0GHz. Both versions of numpy were pip-installed and compiled using GCC-4.8.1.
- I realize my original benchmarking script wasn't totally self-explanatory - you need to divide the total time by the number of loops (1000) in order to get the time per call.
- It also [probably makes more sense to take the minimum across repeats rather than the average](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#python-interface), since this is more likely to represent the lower bound on the execution time (on top of which you'd get variability due to background processes etc.).

**I've updated my script and results above accordingly**

We can also negate any effect of caching across calls (temporal locality) by creating a brand-new random array for every call - just set `nloop` to 1 and `nrep` to a reasonably small number (unless you really enjoy watching paint dry), say 10.

`nloop=1`, `nreps=10` on a 4000x4000 array:

```
numpy version == 1.5.0
row sum:        47.922 us
column sum:     103.235 us

numpy version == 1.8.1
row sum:        66.996 us
column sum:     125.885 us
```

That's a bit more like it, but I still can't really replicate the massive effect that Francesc's slides show. Perhaps this isn't that surprising, though - the effect may be very compiler-, architecture, and/or kernel-dependent.

Comment: @Sebastian Yeah, I have a feeling that particular run might have been a bit of a fluke (also see my updates). Taking the min rather than the mean, I'm now consistently seeing a similar magnitude of difference to you with 1.8.1.

Comment: thanks for the updated script, which results in consistent performance (`number=1`, `repeat=10`): row `~100us`, column `~210us`. So I conclude that there is a factor 2 for the two operations under these circumstances. I cannot, however, trace this back to *cache misses* using the `perf` tool. Both versions have about the same cache misses (~5% of all cache refs).

Comment: I'm seeing about 31% misses for both row and column sums with `nloop=1`, `nreps=10` in numpy 1.8.1. The point of setting the number of loops to 1 is to negate any performance gains due to the array row/column already being cached from the previous call (since it will be a different random array each time), so I was not really expecting to see much difference in cache misses. It's interesting to see that when I go back to `nloop=1000`, `nreps=3` I actually see a slightly *greater* rate of cache misses for the row sum (17% vs 13%), even though it's faster than the column sum.

Comment: right. I see the same trend: *higher rate* of misses by the row summation: `4.3%` V `3.5%` for $n=4000$, but faster summation. PS: I've updated my question with new measurements.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting.  I can reproduce Sebastian's performance:

```
In [21]: np.__version__ 
Out[21]: '1.8.1'

In [22]: a = np.random.randn(4000, 4000)

In [23]: %timeit a[:, 1].sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit a[1, :].sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop
```

However, if I try with a larger array:

```
In [25]: a = np.random.randn(10000, 10000)

In [26]: %timeit a[:, 1].sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit a[1, :].sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.8 µs per loop
```

*but*, if I try again:

```
In [28]: a = np.random.randn(10000, 10000)

In [29]: %timeit a[:, 1].sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.4 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit a[1, :].sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.9 µs per loop
```

so, not sure what's going on here, but this jitter is probably due to cache effects.  Perhaps new architectures are being wiser in predicting pattern access and hence, doing better prefetching?

At any rate, and for comparison matters, I am using NumPy 1.8.1, Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and a laptop with a i5-3380M CPU @ 2.90GHz.

EDIT: After thinking a bit on this, yes I would say that the first time that timeit executes the sum, the column (or the row) is fetched from RAM, but the second time that the operation runs, the data is in cache (for both the row-wise and column-wise versions), so it executes *fast*.  As timeit takes the minimum of the runs, this is why we don't see a big difference in times.

Another question is why we see the difference *sometimes* (using timeit).  But caches are weird beasts, most specially in multicore machines executing multiple processes at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the summation example in *C*: The results are shown for [CPU time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459704/543411) measurements, and I always used `gcc -O1 using-c.c` to compile (gcc version: gcc version 4.9.0 20140604). Source code is below.

I chose the matrix size to be `n x n`. For `n<2k` the row and column summation do not have any measurable difference (6-7 us per run for `n=2k`).

#### Row summation

```
n     first/us      converged/us
 1k       5                 4
 4k      19                12
10k      35                31
20k      70                61
30k     130                90
```

e.g `n=20k`

```
Run 0 taken 70 cycles. 0 ms 70 us
Run 1 taken 61 cycles. 0 ms 60 us # this is the minimum I've seen in all tests
Run 1 taken 61 cycles. 0 ms 61 us
<snip> (always 60/61 cycles)
```

#### Column

```
n     first/us      converged/us
 1k       5                 4
 4k     112                14
10k     228                32
20k     550               246
30k    1000               300
```

e.g  `n=20k`

```
Run 0 taken 552 cycles. 0 ms 552 us
Run 1 taken 358 cycles. 0 ms 358 us
Run 2 taken 291 cycles. 0 ms 291 us
Run 3 taken 264 cycles. 0 ms 264 us
Run 4 taken 252 cycles. 0 ms 252 us
Run 5 taken 275 cycles. 0 ms 275 us
Run 6 taken 262 cycles. 0 ms 262 us
Run 7 taken 249 cycles. 0 ms 249 us
Run 8 taken 249 cycles. 0 ms 249 us
Run 9 taken 246 cycles. 0 ms 246 us
```

#### discussion

Row summation is faster. I doesn't benefit much from any caching, i.e. repeated sums are not much faster than the initial sum. Column summation is much slower, but it steadily increases for 5-8 iterations. The increase is is most pronounced for `n=4k` to `n=10k` where caching helps to increase the speed about tenfold. At larger arrays, the speedup is only about a factor 2. I also observe that while row summation converges very quickly (after one or two trials), column summation convergence takes many more iterations (5 or more).

Take away lesson for me:

- For large arrays (more than 2k elements) there is a difference in summation speed. I believe this is due to synergies when fetching data from RAM to L1d cache. Although I don't know the block/line size of one read, I assume it is larger than 8 bytes. So the next element to sum up is already in the cache.
- Column sum speed is first and foremost limited by memory bandwidth. The CPU seems to starve for data as the spread out chunks are read from RAM.
- When performing the summation repeatedly, one expects that some data doesn't need to be fetched from RAM and is already present in L2/L1d cache. For row summation, this is noticeable only for `n>30k`, for column summation it becomes apparent already at `n>2k`.

Using `perf`, I don't see a large difference though. But the bulk work of the C program is filling the array with random data. I don't know how I can eliminate this "setup" data...

Here Is the *C* code for this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // see `man random`
#include <time.h> // man  time.h, info clock

int
main (void)
{
  // seed
  srandom(62);
  //printf ("test %g\n", (double)random()/(double)RAND_MAX);
  const size_t SIZE = 20E3;
  const size_t RUNS = 10;
  double (*b)[SIZE];
  printf ("Array size: %dx%d, each %d bytes. slice = %f KiB\n", SIZE, SIZE, 
      sizeof(double), ((double)SIZE)*sizeof(double)/1024);

  b = malloc(sizeof *b * SIZE);

  //double a[SIZE][SIZE]; // too large!
  int i,j;
  for (i = 0; i< SIZE; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      b[i][j] = (double)random()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    }
  }
  double sum = 0;
  int run = 0;
  clock_t start, diff;
  int usec;
  for (run = 0; run < RUNS; run++) {
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
      // column wise (slower?)
      sum += b[i][1];
      // row wise (faster?)
      //sum += b[1][i];
    }
    diff = clock() - start;
    usec = ((double) diff*1e6) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // https://stackoverflow.com/a/459704/543411
    printf("Run %d taken %d cycles. %d ms %d us\n",run, diff, usec/1000, usec%1000);
  }
  printf("Sum: %g\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Numpy 1.9.0.def-ff7d5f9, and I see a 10x difference when executing the two test lines you posted. I wouldn't be surprised if your machine and what compiler you've used to build Numpy is as important to the speedup as the Numpy version is.

In practice though, I don't think it's too common to want to do a reduction of a single column or row like this. I think a better test would be to compare reducing across all rows

```
a.sum(axis=0)
```

with reducing across all columns

```
a.sum(axis=1)
```

For me, these two operations have only a small difference in speed (reducing across columns takes about 95% of the time of reducing across rows).

**EDIT:** In general, I'm very wary about comparing the speed of operations that take on the order of microseconds. When installing Numpy, it's very important to have a good [BLAS library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) linked with it, since this is what does the heavy lifting when it comes to most large matrix operations (such as matrix-matrix multiplies). When comparing BLAS libraries, you definitely want to use intensive operations like matrix-matrix dot products as the point of comparison, since this is where you'll spend the vast majority of your time. I've found that sometimes, a worse BLAS library will actually have a slightly faster vector-vector dot operation than a better BLAS library. What makes it worse, though, is that operations like matrix-matrix dot products and eigenvalue decompositions take tens of times longer, and these matter much more than a cheap vector-vector dot. I think these differences often appear because you can write a reasonably fast vector-vector dot in C without much thought, but writing a good matrix-matrix dot takes a lot of thought and optimization, and is the more costly operation, so this is where good BLAS packages put their effort.

The same is true in Numpy: any optimization is going to be done on larger operations, not small ones, so don't get hung up on speed differences between small operations. Furthermore, it's hard to tell if any speed difference with a small operation is really due the time of the computation, or is just due to overhead that is put in to optimize more costly operations.

Comment: Do you know how I find out which BLAS I'm using? I don't remember if I changed the default.

Comment: Sebastian, in this example BLAS is not used at all.  Hunse's advice of use BLAS whenever you can is good, but to no effect for this case.

Comment: @sebastian: Ahh, yes, sorry. I meant to mention that these reductions do not use BLAS. I just brought that up because when trying to set up my BLAS, I did a lot of benchmarking, and realized that measuring the time of short operations, such as your single-row reductions, is not indicative of real-world performance. That said, to check your BLAS use `numpy.show_config()`.