# How to set read() to non-blocking mode

Tags: linux, file-io

I have a problem at present when calling read() like this:

```
unsigned char byData[1024] = {0};
ssize_t len = read(fd, byData, sizeof(byData));
```

where fd is the file descriptor.

read() is blocking which is not what I want.
Is there a simple way to set read to non-blocking or time out?
The code is used with inotify.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See http://cr.yp.to/unix/nonblock.html (in short: alter the fd as in the answers below, not read())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-blocking call for reading descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616092/non-blocking-call-for-reading-descriptor)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot make such system calls non-blocking; rather, you can make the file descriptor they work on non-blocking

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)
```

or

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0); fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

if you need to add `O_NONBLOCK` and preserve the previously set flags.

That way `read` will not block. If you want to set a timeout, use `select` or `poll`

```
fd_set fds; 
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fd, &fds);

struct timeval t = {/*seconds*/, /*microseconds*/};
select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &t);
```

The error handling and following work(`select` will overwrite both `fds` and `t`) is left to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) on the file descriptor to know when there is data to read. And then, call `read()`.

```
# Poll definition
int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
```

as you can see you can set a timeout. This is usefull for situations where the file can' t be opened with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag, or you aren't calling `open()` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Call the `open(fd, ...)` with `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

From `open()` man page:

> **O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY:** When possible, the file is opened in
>   nonblocking mode.  Neither the open() nor any subsequent operations on
>   the  file descriptor  which  is  returned  will cause the calling
>   process to wait.  For the handling of FIFOs (named pipes), see also
>   fifo(7).  For a discussion of the effect of O_NONBLOCK in conjunction
>   with mandatory file  locks  and  with  file leases, see fcntl(2).

Comment: Unfortunately the code I'm using doesn't call open.  This is the code   :                                                             s_MyRes.wd = inotify_add_watch (s_MyRes.fd, ctx.szFolder.c_str(), ctx.uMask);  After this, read() is called, which is blocking.

Answer (score -1):

This topic has already been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616092/non-blocking-call-for-reading-descriptor).

Also you can try [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459691/best-timing-method-in-c) or thread.
Here is the example of thread

```
#include <pthread.h>

unsigned char byData[1024] = {0};
ssize_t len;

void *thread(arguments) {
  while (1) {
    len = read(fd, byData, sizeof(byData));
  }

int main(){
  pthread_t pth;
  pthread_create(&pth, NULL, thread, arguments);
}
```